# Can Java output variable names and data values in error logs?

Tags: java, backtrace

(I'm not a Java programmer, just an end-user trying to deal with a lack of exception handling and reporting in someone else's code.)

Is there a way to get more detailed info such as variable names and values from Java when it back-traces an unhandled exception?

This is in regards to a Minecraft server log, apparently there's a corrupt chunk file somewhere. The error trace seems too vague to tell me exactly where the problem is located, such as the specific datafile name involved in the error.

```
2013-12-16 11:19:03 [WARNING] Failed to handle packet for PlayerName [/XX.XX.XX.XX:5046]: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -448550
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:371)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:399)
    at net.minecraft.world.chunk.storage.RegionFile.<init>(RegionFile.java:89)
    at net.minecraft.world.chunk.storage.RegionFileCache.func_76550_a(SourceFile:61)
    at net.minecraft.world.chunk.storage.AnvilChunkLoader.chunkExists(AnvilChunkLoader.java:63)
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.getChunkAt(ChunkProviderServer.java:167)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerInstance.<init>(PlayerInstance.java:38)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerManager.func_72690_a(PlayerManager.java:116)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerManager.func_72683_a(PlayerManager.java:175)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.ServerConfigurationManager.func_72375_a(ServerConfigurationManager.java:269)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.ServerConfigurationManager.func_72377_c(ServerConfigurationManager.java:335)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.ServerConfigurationManager.func_72355_a(ServerConfigurationManager.java:180)
    at net.minecraft.network.NetLoginHandler.completeConnection(NetLoginHandler.java:218)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.network.FMLNetworkHandler.handleClientConnection(FMLNetworkHandler.java:171)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.network.FMLNetworkHandler.onConnectionReceivedFromClient(FMLNetworkHandler.java:124)
    at net.minecraft.network.NetLoginHandler.func_72529_d(NetLoginHandler.java:194)
    at net.minecraft.network.NetLoginHandler.func_72532_c(NetLoginHandler.java:81)
    at net.minecraft.server.ServerListenThread.func_71766_a(ServerListenThread.java:57)
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServerListenThread.func_71747_b(SourceFile:29)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:865)
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71190_q(DedicatedServer.java:320)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:732)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:614)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadMinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:573)
```

From the logs, I understand that a player is trying to log on, and it's loading the world data where the player was last located, but a region file is corrupt and an array in the file data is invalid.

But which region file? It doesn't tell me that.

Can these error logs be made to be more verbose with variable names and values, such as with an extra startup java command line setting?

I'm finding very little to explain how to even interpret these back traces. I assume the numbers at the end of each line are referring to line numbers within the source code, but I'm not able to edit the code so examining the source at those lines would not help anyway.

Environment: Ubuntu 13.10

java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Not local variables, not. The only variables' names you can get are field names and, some times, through much hardship, parameter names.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think that he referred to the *value* of a variable (which is the file-name)

Comment: Do you know [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)? Its a better alternative for debugging via logs.

Comment: I am not (yet) a java programmer so I am not familiar with any debugging tools other than the default backtraces shown above. I recognize OpenJDK is a developer's kit Java, which may offer its own advanced debug tools, but I only know how to launch jars from the bash command line at this point.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code that produces the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You really want to learn how to use a source-level debugger. These will let you step through the code, stopping at interesting points or when an exception is thrown, and examine (and often even modify) variable values.

Which is best is very much a matter of taste, but I'm going to break the rule here and suggest you try the Eclipse environment simply because it's the only IDE I've ever used which really does a good job of integrating code authoring, debugging, and management.

(The Java runtime environment does have its own debugger, which can do most of the same things -- but it's a commandline tool and I think it's significantly harder for a novice to learn. There are times when it's the right tool, mostly when you have to work remotely over a very limited connection, but I don't suggest you start with it.)

Comment: This assumes the user has access to source code, nothing from the original question makes that clear.  Changing the JVM to log "more verbosely" seems to be the question being asked.

Comment: you can do debugging very easily without source also. All you need is a way to analyze the variables and parameters. Its a bit hard but doable and very crafty. Honestly for debugging in eclipse/nb all you need is class files as bare minimal and it can get you started. Source accessibility is a plus as it allows you to see what code is being executed. Nothing more.

Comment: In many cases, source-level debugger is 0verkill, as wanting the parameter values would basically be just a workaround for the relevant information failing to be included in the exception message. That is, the exception is probably a configuration error, but without knowing the values you can't tell where. Then you don't want to fiddle with a debugger; just having it print the values would be enough.